# How to grant ReflectionPermission with RestrictedMemberAccess to my application C#

Tags: c#, security, reflection, permissions, reflectionpermission

When I call GetTypes on the assembly I cannot see internal and private classes.
I read I can get internal and private classes by adding RestrictedMemberAccess but I don't know how to do it.

```
Assembly assemlib = typeof(TabletDeviceCollection).Assembly;

foreach (Type type in assemlib.GetTypes())
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
}
```

Thanks for any help.